# PHPStorm - Wrong root folder? Full path

Tags: php, path, phpstorm

I have just installed PHPStorm and i'm using MAMP on my mac as local server. I have created a PHP Project and wanted do require_once() to a file which is inside a folder called functions.

But when i want to refer to that file i can't just type "/" infront of it. I have type the full path like: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/functions

What have i done wrong?

None of these is found:

```
require_once '/functions/sanitize.php';

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

But this one works fine:

```
require_once '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/functions/sanitize.php';
```

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: This inspection (include/require statements) looks for files relative to: 1) current file; 2) project root; 3) include paths configured in IDE. If such include file is located outside of project .. and not referenced via include paths .. then it will not be found. I personally just disabling this inspection .. but then -- I'm using class autoloading and not include/require.

Comment: php has an include_path, just like your shell has a $PATH for looking for executables. you need to put your script somewhere inside that include_path, and then you also need to learn the difference between a relative `functions/...` and absolute `/functions/...` path.

Comment: Marc B - I know the differents about absolute path and relative. Im not sure what you mean about putting my script inside the include_path. Can i see that path somewhere?